# Stack Overflow no longer in New York?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, email

I received today email from Stack Overflow (new job matches) and was amazed to see this:

> [image]

Bentima House, London. That's not where Stack Overflow main office is located. Just to make sure, I went to a similar email about job matches I got less than a month ago (January 17) and indeed:

> [image]

So, what's going on? Did Stack Overflow change their main office? Or is this some weird bug?

Looking at other emails (e.g. tag subscription emails) the address there is still New York, so it happens only with Jobs emails.

Comment: Stack Overflow does also have a London office, where they have a lot of Careers work  in progress..

Comment: @MartijnPieters but still, address was always New York, including on emails from Jobs.

Comment: That *is* where our London office is, but just checking how we determine what office location to render in the emails...

Comment: @Dean thanks, wonder if it's really a bug....

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well this was a fun exercise... When we moved the candidate-facing pieces of Careers over to /jobs we didn't need localization anymore so we switched all candidate emails to use our default language code (en-US).

When we generate an email we use the language code specified by the user's account to render things like the office address. This is helpful for employers because it lets them know the office they should be in touch with, not so much so for candidates... Your original Careers account must have been set to be en-GB, de-DE or fr-FR to have rendered the UK office address.

I've just pushed a change that forces the use of the default language code everywhere for candidate emails so they'll now use the NY address instead.

Comment: Glad you had fun! ;)

Comment: BTW, how you read the language code? From the browser, I assume? Don't remember ever seeing such a setting in Careers.

Comment: In Careers (or Talent as it's now known) we have links at the bottom of the page that allow you to set the language. Or you can visit any URL with a /uk, /de or /fr prefix. We don't do any language detection right now